# currvita - resume section without bullets

Tags: sectioning, cv, currvita

I like `currvita` class very much.

I have problem with creating section without bullets. I would like to add section "additional information" and use full available width.

I've found three solutions, each of them is not perfect :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[TextAligned,NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\settowidth{\cvlabelwidth}{\cvlabelfont {May 2012-present XX}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{cv}{John Doe}

\begin{cvlist}{Additional Information} % ok
\item[] %empty bullet is wrong (due to spacing, but it's required by cvlist)
\end{cvlist}
\lipsum[1-2] % ok

\begin{cvlist}{Additional Information} % ok
\item[]
\lipsum[1-2] % test is wrong (not full width, because it's bullet)
\end{cvlist}

\section*{Additional Information} %heading is wrong
\lipsum[1-2] % ok

\begin{cvlist}{Other section example} %other sections are ok
\item[Feb 2006--Feb 2012] {\bf Lipsum}\\
\lipsum[3]
\item[May 2000--May 2006] {\bf Lipsum}\\
\lipsum[3]
\end{cvlist}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

While "other" sections are ok and I would like to not affect their rendering.

How to make section without bullets using full width ?
(setting `\cvlabelwidth = 0` still makes no full width, due to bullet indentation. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\subsection*` instead of `\section*`:

```
\subsection*{Additional Information}
\lipsum[1-2]
```